# Cross domain Request

Tags: ajax, cross-domain

```
 How to get response headers using xdr object...

  xdr.getResponseHeader('abc');
```

This throws a error as it is not supported by xdr.. may i know what is the alternative to get header information for cross domain

Answer (score 0):

There is simply no way to send or retrieve headers via XDomainRequest.  The only alternative is to not send cross origin requests in IE9 and older, so you can rely on XMLHttpRequest instead.